# Steps to Simplify Boolean Expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Could someone please example how

$(\bar A . \bar B . \bar C) + (\bar A . \bar B . C) + (A . B . \bar C) + (A . B . C)$

can be simplified to

$(\bar A . \bar B) + (A . B)$ ?

Here's what I've tried, but I don't trust all the steps:

$(\bar A . \bar B . \bar C) + (\bar A . \bar B . C) + (A . B . \bar C) + (A . B . C)$

$(\bar A . \bar B . \bar C) + (A . B . \bar C) + (\bar A . \bar B . C) + (A . B . C)$

$\bar C . ((\bar A . \bar B ) + (A . B)) + C . ((\bar A . \bar B) + (A . B))$

$(\bar C + C) . ((\bar A . \bar B ) + (A . B) + (\bar A . \bar B) + (A . B))$

$(\bar A . \bar B ) + (A . B) + (\bar A . \bar B) + (A . B)$

$2 . (\bar A . \bar B ) + 2 . (A . B)$

Now I'm stuck. Am I right so far? If so, why can I cancel those $2$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Michael Rozenberg has already explained how to reduce the expression. Your method is also correct until this point:

$(\bar A . \bar B ) + (A . B) + (\bar A . \bar B) + (A . B)$

At this point, remember the laws of Boolean Algebra, which state that A + A = A. That allows you to simplify the expression further to $(\bar A . \bar B ) + (A . B) $, which is the desired result

Comment: Ah, so you never have coefficients of a term, like 2(AB), then?

Comment: Yeah, because we are dealing with binary values. There is nothing like more true or more false, only true or false, so A, 2A, 3A, and so on are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\bar A \bar B \bar C + \bar A  \bar BC + AB\bar C + ABC=$$
$$=\bar{A}\bar{B}(\bar{C}+C)+AB(\bar{C}+C)=\bar{A}\bar{B}+AB.$$

Comment: Thanks for that. Would my steps also work, even though I took a less efficient route?

Comment: @Robin By your way we obtain: $(\bar{C}+C)(\bar{A}\bar{B}+AB)=\bar{A}\bar{B}+AB.$

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?